# Как перехватывать события активации дочерней формы в mdi приложении?

Tags: delphi

Хочу словить событие активации child формы в mdi приложении. Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью хелперов:

```
TFormHelper = class helper for TForm
public
  procedure WMMDIACTIVATE(var msg: TWMMDIACTIVATE); message WM_MDIACTIVATE;
end;
```

...

```
procedure TFormHelper.WMMDIACTIVATE(var msg: TWMMDIACTIVATE);
begin
  ShowMessage('1');
end;
```

В чем тут ошибка? Может есть более правильный способ отловить активацию формы? Знаю что можно написать обертку на `TForm` и наследоваться от нее, но не хотелось бы менять родителя во всех формах.

Answer (score 2):

Понятия не имею, как это на самом деле реализовано (и вообще на дельфи не программирую), а гугл упорно ничего находить не хочет, поэтому описанное ниже считать гипотезой. Помогло бы, если бы вы включили текст ошибки, если таковая присутствует.

Class helper — синтаксический сахар над статическими функциями, которые первым (неявным) параметром принимают `self`, как и обычные инстансные функциии. Хелперы и их методы никаким образом не сказываются на иерархии классов, поэтому в них не может быть виртуальных методов.

Функции с атрибутом `message` — это синтаксический сахар над `WndProc (var Msg: TMessage); override;` с `case` по всем сообщениям, которые есть в объявлении класса, и вызовом `WndProc` базового типа.

Как можно видеть, эти две синтаксические конструкции несовместимы в принципе. Добавление хелпера не может влиять на поведение всех существующих классов-наследников от заданного типа — это всего лишь набор отдельных функций.

Правильный способ — это переопределять `WndProc` в нужных вам формах. По крайней мере, если нет возможности подписаться на событие извне, то есть событие `WM_MDIACTIVATE` не вытащено во внешний интерфейс (полагаю, что не вытащено, иначе вы бы не спрашивали). Ещё есть костыли через `SetWindowLong` с `GWL_WNDPROC`, но лучше этим не пользоваться, потому что весь смысл VCL в том, чтобы скрывать эти детали, и шут знает, чем обернётся заход с заднего крыльца.